Cannot connect to MySQL database with C++ Desktop App, Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to create a C++ app using MySQL Workbench to develop the database.  I have it created, and using a database called db.  I've checked the local server and it is running, but every time I try and establish a connection with my program (Using a login button), it gives the error "Failed to connect to database: 0"
In the output I get this.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCB2275B0C in CardMart.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x000000FD700FB7E0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCB2275B0C in CardMart.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x000000FD700FCEC0.
I am not sure if I am including everything, if I need more, please let me know.
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        /*    */
        case LOGIN_BUTTON: // Login button was clicked
        {
            wchar_t username[256], password[256];
            GetWindowText(User_Box, username, 256);
            GetWindowText(Password_Box, password, 256);

            // Convert WCHAR to std::string or directly use wide character strings in your SQL queries depending on your setup
            // This example shows a simple conversion to ANSI strings for demonstration purposes
            char usernameA[256], passwordA[256];
            size_t usernameA_size, passwordA_size;

            wcstombs_s(&usernameA_size, usernameA, sizeof(usernameA), username, _TRUNCATE);
            wcstombs_s(&passwordA_size, passwordA, sizeof(passwordA), password, _TRUNCATE);

            try {
                sql::Driver* driver;
                sql::Connection* con;
                std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt;
                std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

                /* Create a connection */
                driver = get_driver_instance();
                con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

                /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
                con->setSchema("db");

                // Confirmation of successful connection
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Successfully connected to the database.", L"Database Connection", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

            }
            catch (sql::SQLException& e) {
                std::wstring error_message = L"Failed to connect to database: ";
                error_message += std::to_wstring(e.getErrorCode());
                MessageBox(hWnd, error_message.c_str(), L"Database Error", MB_ICONERROR);
            }
        }
        break;


exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x000000FD700FCEC0. What  did the exception tell you? This should have given you a message if you continued into your catch (sql::SQLException& e) {

Are you sure the server is listening on TCP? If it's just for local use, it may only use a Unix-domain socket.

@drescherjm I don't know how to find the exception.

Press F5 after it breaks into the debugger. Your code should popup a message box with the error. I suspect you have an incorrect password because of this line: con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root"); which tells it that the user and password are both root.

@drescherjm I set them both to root just to debug since it was easier, pressing f5 doesn't do anything, other than relaunches it.
It doesn't break into the debugger, the window that comes up says "Failed to connect to database: 0"

I expected it to have said "Failed to connect to database: " + added some additional info.

Type netstat -na | find "3306" in  a cmd.exe window to see if mysql is listening on port 3306. If that returns nothing look at the output for netstat -na or even netstat -na | find "LIST" to see what ports are listening.

@drescherjm
I got this
TCP   0.0.0.0:3306    0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING
TCP   0.0.0.0:33060  0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING
TCP   127.0.0.1:3306  127.0.0.1:52295  ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:3306    127.0.0.1:52296    ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:3306    127.0.0.1:52297   ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:3306    127.0.0.1:52298        ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:52295    127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:52296   127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:52297    127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP   127.0.0.1:52298  127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED

I am not sure why it won't connect.

I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add a solution to the question. If you've found one and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See Can I answer my own question? for more details.

Your solution to switch from debug mode to release mode makes me think the problem is mixing debug and release libraries. In msvc it's not safe to mix debug and release as a result if a third party does not have separate release and debug libraries many times you will only be limited to release. This could also be why the message from SQLException didn't contain a descriptive error.
